# Track down heap corruption by allocating lots of memory?

Tags: c++, debugging, heap-corruption

In my program I am encountering the following error:

```
free(): invalid size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Running GDB I find that this occurs in the destructor of a vector:

```
#0  0x00007ffff58e8c01 in free () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000555555dd44e2 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate (this=0x7fffffff6bf0, __p=0x555557117810) at /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:125
#2  0x0000555555dcfbd7 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x555557117810, __n=1) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:462
#3  0x0000555555dc85e6 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffff6bf0, __p=0x555557117810, __n=1)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:180
#4  0x0000555555dc49e1 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffff6bf0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:162
#5  0x0000555555dbc5c9 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffff6bf0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:435
#6  0x0000555556338081 in Gambit::Printers::HDF5Printer2::get_buffer_idcodes[abi:cxx11](std::vector<Gambit::Printers::HDF5MasterBuffer*, std::allocator<Gambit::Printers::HDF5MasterBuffer*> > const&) (this=0x555556fd8820, masterbuffers=...) at /home/farmer/repos/gambit/copy3/Printers/src/printers/hdf5printer_v2/hdf5printer_v2.cpp:2183
```

where that last line of code is simply:

```
std::vector<int> alllens(myComm.Get_size());
```

So firstly, I don't quite get why the destructor is called here, but supposing it is a normal part of how the vector is dynamically constructed then I guess this error must be due to some sort of heap corruption.

I don't quite get it fully though, is the idea that some other part of the code has previously illegally accessed the memory that is supposed to be allocated for this vector?

Second, I have tried running this through Intel Inspector, and I do get a bunch of "Invalid memory access" and "Uninitialized memory access" problems flagged, but they all look like false positives in libraries I am using, like HDF5.

Is there some in-code way of narrowing down where exactly the problem is coming from? E.g. since it gets triggered by a dynamic memory allocation, can I just start allocating huge arrays earlier and earlier in the code to try and trigger the crash closer to where it originates? I tried searching around for whether something like that would work or be helpful but didn't find anything about it, so maybe it is not a good idea?

Comment: *is the idea that some other part of the code has previously illegally accessed the memory that is supposed to be allocated for this vector?* That is a likely scenario.  The best way to find the problem is to try an make a [mre]

Comment: Considering that you use GDB chances are that you are on a platform supported by [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org). I suggest using it (or similar tools) to find out memory problems like yours.

Comment: Oh I tried Valgrind but it just crashes. Seems like it is not compatible with my version of MPICH or some such. That is why I went to Intel Inspector. Would Valgrind find something that Intel Inspector doesn't?

Comment: @BenFarmer *where that last line of code is simply:* -- What exactly do you mean by "the last line of code"?  The last line in a `{ }` block?  If so, that looks very strange why anyone would write code to create a vector locally, and (since it is the last line) have it destroyed immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it is hdf5printer_v2.cpp:2183, the line of code mentioned in frame #6 of the backtrace, which ultimately triggers the error. It is just in the middle of the program somewhere.

Comment: To narrow it down, one could assume that the problem is that you write out of bounds of the `alllens` vector. With that assumption you could add logging for all writes into the vector, where each logging entry contains the element being written to as well as the current size. Then when a crash happens you check this log to see if any index is out of bounds (negative or equal to or larger than the size).

Comment: There are no writes into that vector, the crash is exactly the line I listed, where the vector is first declared/constructed.

Comment: Okay then, how about backing up to when the crash started appearing? You *do* use some kind of source-control and versioning system? When did the crash starting to appear? What changes were made around that time? Do some review of the code added then, and add logging for that code. Or just rollback to before the crash appeared, and go forward one checkin at a time until it happens. Then you know exactly what change introduced the crash and where to look.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that I was corrupting the heap via some of the MPI routines, i.e. incorrect parameters for buffer lengths and so on. Unfortunately lots of crazy stuff goes on in the MPI libraries so memory analyzers like Intel Inspector weren't that useful in finding it.

However, I learned about Address Sanitizer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) that comes with modern GNU compilers, and that turned out to be great! Compiled against it in my CMake project (from https://gist.github.com/jlblancoc/44be9d4d466f0a973b1f3808a8e56782)

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address  -fsanitize=leak -g" 
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address  -fsanitize=leak -g"
  -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address  -fsanitize=leak"
  -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address  -fsanitize=leak"
```

Ran it with

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS=fast_unwind_on_malloc=0
```

(No idea if that was really neccesary), and received a fantastic backtrace when my heap corruption occurred:

```
==12748==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000521340 at pc 0x7fda5011577a bp 0x7ffe231c55e0 sp 0x7ffe231c4d88
WRITE of size 32 at 0x602000521340 thread T0
    #0 0x7fda50115779  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0x79779)
    #1 0x7fda4fcd84e3  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.0+0xf24e3)
    #2 0x7fda4fc228d7  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.0+0x3c8d7)
    #3 0x7fda4fc23a26  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.0+0x3da26)
    #4 0x7fda4fc2316c  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.0+0x3d16c)
    #5 0x7fda4fc2406c in PMPI_Gather (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.0+0x3e06c)
    #6 0x55e0c18586b0 in void Gambit::GMPI::Comm::Gather<unsigned long>(std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >&, int) /home/farmer/repos/gambit/copy3/Utils/include/gambit/Utils/mpiwrapper.hpp:450
    ...etc...
```

Which pointed straight at the MPI call that I screwed up. Amazing!

But to answer my OP question, my idea of allocating lots of heap memory to trigger the crash closer to the problem wasn't really working. Not sure why. I guess I just don't understand what is going on under the hood there. In fact the place I was seeing the crash was *before* the MPI call in my code, so that was quite confusing. I guess the compiler moved some stuff around? I did have optimisations turned off, but I guess operations could still be ordered differently in the binary than I expect?